# Where can qrc resources get lost if they are compiled into the binary correctly?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

For my project, I have pixmaps in a `.qrc` file. I can see that the qrc generated header files contain the names of my pixmaps, and they are definitely compiled into the binary. However, the pictures do not load (they are empty in the GUI), and the following code

```
QDirIterator it(":", QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
while (it.hasNext()) {
    qDebug() << it.next();
}
```

outputs none of them.

I tried to make a minimal example, but could not recreate the bug (the images show up). Anyway, the example shows how I compiled it. See [this link here](https://github.com/JohannesLorenz/icon_example). Any idea how to find this bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your qrc is compiled into a library before being linked to your application, you may need to call `Q_INIT_RESOURCE` in your executable, typically within main().

> Normally, Qt resources are loaded automatically at startup. The Q_INIT_RESOURCE() macro is necessary on some platforms for resources stored in a static library.

More details on `Q_INIT_RESOURCE` can be found in the [QDir documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qdir.html#Q_INIT_RESOURCE).

Comment: Very good! My GUI was indeed a static library, and this call saved the problem.